# Graph API - Is it possible to calculate time spent on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am not sure, whether graph api has any function for this.

I want to know how many hours per day i have (other users) spent on facebook in the last one week or last month.

Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, but beware of overflow.

Comment: @Rom1, I didnt get your point. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's not possible with graph api as there is no such value.

however, you could track e.g. the time spent on your app but you'd have to write that mechanism yourself.

Comment: No. I dont want to track time spent on apps. Just wanted to know whether it is possible to track the time spent on facebook. I just saw one app sometime ago saying "you have spent 8.4h ave on facebook" - I dont know how they did it. I lost the app link too

Comment: http://i43.tinypic.com/xdz1ok.jpg -- This is the image of the app. How did they do this?

Comment: @Kamini I think they are just spinning.